# Como retornar Latitude e longitude no Android Google-Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Gostaria de saber como posso retornar latitude e longitude a partir de um endereço fornecido pelo Usuário.

Exemplo `"Av. Sampaio Vidal,Centro, Marília, SP"`

Resposta  `coordenadas -22.225985,-49.94656`

Answer (score 5):

Você quer realizar uma operação de *geocoding*.

Use o método [Geocoder.getFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String,%20int,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double)).

Ele retornará uma lista de objetos [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html), que por sua vez possuem os métodos `Address.getLatitude()` e `Address.getLongitude()`.

### Exemplo

(Não testado, na verdade deveria ser modificado para trazer os dados em um *thread* à parte, pois é pesado demais para o *thread* principal do Android):

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> enderecos = geocoder.getFromLocationName("Av. Sampaio Vidal, Centro, Marília, SP", 1);
if (enderecos.size() > 0) {
    Log.v("tag", "coordenadas " + enderecos.get(0).getLatitude() + ", " + enderecos.get(0).getLongitude());
}
```

Comment: puts estou com um erro  `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`
na linha `Log.v("tag", "coordenadas " + enderecos.get(0).getLatitude() + ", " + enderecos.get(0).getLongitude());`

Comment: Isso quer dizer que a lista de objetos `Address` veio vazia, isto é, o Google não encontrou um endereço próximo das coordenadas informadas. Alterei o código da resposta para incluir esse teste.

Comment: Ops, na verdade quis dizer o contrário, que o Google não encontrou coordenadas para o endereço informado.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente isso não será a resposta mas é só pra tentar dar uma luz: eu consigo as coordenadas extraindo-as de uma consulta da seguinte forma:

`URL PERMANENTE`: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=

`ENDEREÇO`: Av. Sampaio Vidal,Centro, Marília, SP

Concatena a url com o endereço e terá `tudo` sobre a consulta executada dentro de um `array`, bastando então extrair os dados que desejar.

`Exemplo`: [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Av. Sampaio Vidal,Centro, Marília, SP](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Av.%20Sampaio%20Vidal,Centro,%20Mar%C3%ADlia,%20SP)

**Sucesso**